# Regex - check if a substring is not part of a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to check in a given string that if the word *TEST* appears in the string then it is NOT inside the pattern ([]). 
The regex should return **true** for the following example strings:

- TEST
- this is my ([TEST
- this is my TEST]) number 2
- ([bla]) TEST ([bla])

Should return **false** for the following example strings:

- this is my ([TEST]) oops
- this is my ([bla TEST bla])
- this is my ([TEST TEST])
- string without the tes* word

thanks

Comment: What about `([TEST TEST])`? Does that match or not?

Comment: How about `([bla]) TEST ([bla])`?

Comment: @svinja the regex should match for ([bla]) TEST ([bla]) since the pattern is closed before the TEST word. great catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookaheads regex:

```
^(?!.*\(\[(?:(?!\(\[|\]\)).)*TEST(?:(?!\(\[|\]\)).)*\]\))(?=.*TEST).*
```

- `(?!..)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if `([..TEST..])` appears anywhere in the line.
- `(?=.*TEST)` is positive lookahead to ensure that line contains `TEST`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY3qR0/4)

Comment: it fails for `([bla]) [TEST]([bla])`

Comment: That's not correct as `([bla]) [TEST]([bla])` comes as a match in the demo link.

Comment: sorry.. that's what I meant

Comment: it says that it's a match.. but for what I understood, it shouldn't point that as a match

Comment: @Hugo it should come as a match. anubhava thanks a lot!

Comment: Any idea why ([TEST]) TEST is not found as match?

Comment: It is not matching because it has `([TEST])` which is not allowed as per requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
/\[.*TEST.*\]/g
```

inverse of what you asked ([see Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS1jL8/1)), just do a '!' before match

Comment: You might want to change your answer slightly since the flavor has been established as Java. Conceptually, your answer is fine though.

Comment: could you please explain the '!' before match?

Comment: @user1116377 Invert the boolean that indicates if there is a match.